# copy term reference from one to other field

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have two fields (fieldtype = term reference) in the same content type and I would like to copy the settings from the first to the second one. After searching for a solution I found [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/1000200) but I think the description I need is just the one that is not available:

> "Copy contents of a CCK node reference field to another CCK node
>   reference field"

Can somebody give me some guidelines, or even an explanation how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to copy the field settings or the field value? when do you want to copy the value?

Comment: Good question David, now your asking that, I have to admit I used the wrong description. I would like to copy the field value, not the settings. This has to be done once for almost all my content items (nodes). I think I can use VBO for that but not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: David, did you have perhaps also have an explanation how to archieve the copy action I described?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = 'my_type'");
foreach($result as $row){
  $node = node_load($row->nid, NULL, TRUE); // reset cache
  // Assign one node reference field to another
  $node->field_termreference_2 = $node->field_termreference_1;
  node_save($node);
}
```

If you've got a lot of nodes, you may need to use the [Batch API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/batch/7) for that.

Alternatively, you may be able to copy the field tables to another field table at the database level with SQL ( backup first )

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO field_data_field_termreference_2 SELECT * FROM field_data_field_termreference_1;
INSERT INTO field_revision_field_termreference_2 SELECT * FROM field_revision_field_termreference_1;
```

and clear Drupal caches after that.

Comment: Thanks David..Not sure where to put the code you've given me. I think I give it a try to use execute the SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue last week.
If you want you can try the sandbox project I created with the working title ["field_value_copy"](http://drupal.org/sandbox/pontusnilsson/1932784)

It uses Entity API to load, fetch values and set them on the target field.

Put the module in you modules folder, run drush cache-clear drush and the you execute the command with

```
drush fieldcopy field_termreference_1 field_termreference_2 my_content_type
```

If you want to try it on just one node you can run

```
drush fieldcopy field_termreference_1 field_termreference_2 my_content_type node 12
```

where 12 is the node id.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what David Thomas said, about using INSERT INTO SELECT statement, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html - reference

INSERT INTO field_data_field_[term reference 2] SELECT * FROM field_data_field_[term reference 1];

I was able to use the above insert statement to copy term/table to another term reference table.

MySQL approach is a simple solution and works for my use case because how often will I need to merge or copy from one term reference to another? If I'm writing a module it would make sense. If I'm doing this just once, MySQL is simpler solution.

- Sam